# Edit group in Skype

Tags: windows, skype

I created a group of contacts in Skype. It is now in my contact list. 
How can I edit this group (add and remove members) without the need of dropping and recreating the group?

I use Skype 5.8.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click on the group in your contact list, the chat window is opened.

To add a new member to the group, you can simply drag and drop a member from your contact list to the upper list of members where you can see their avatars.

To remove a member you can right click on its avatar and choose "remove".